# IE9 background image 1 white px :(

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, rounded-corners

this is my website

http://www.forid.ir

it is not english but my question is just about the search box (it has an icon and is obvious)

about the curves in search box if your browser is NOT IE9 you can see everything works currectly. (including IE8-)

but if you use IE9 there is a single white pixel at the right corner, i have no idea what causes ie to behave like this :(

between corners i have an input which has the appropriate border i have tried lots of possibilities but it doesn't work the last option is to forget about the curves and have an image for the whole input background.

it's the worst English i've ever used!! so sorry it is hard to explain.

Comment: Interestingly the pixel disappears if you remove the explicit width, or zoom the browser view.

Comment: Try to set the outline: none; margin: 0; padding:0; float: right; for the search_form

Comment: @Jay i tried didn't work

Comment: @Joey yes .. i really don't understand IE9 ..

Comment: Well, other browsers have similarly obscure and abstruse bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be related to `direction: rtl` on `body`. At least, when I toggle that off, the problem disappears.

For a lack of any better ideas, you could fix it with a [conditional comment](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html):

```html
<!--[if IE 9]>
<style>
#sr_right {
    margin-left: -1px;
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: while new ideas are appreciated, this one works just fine thank you.
and thank you for the knowledge, i didn't know that margin can be negative.

Comment: You're welcome. Could you [accept this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) if it's good enough? If a better answer comes along in the future, you can accept that instead.

Comment: Note that conditional comments stop working in IE10 and I guess the rendering engine won't have changed in that regard there.